# Calculating pullback using inclusion vs. pullback using chart

Tags: differential-forms

Consider the following form on $\mathbb R^{2n + 2}$:

$$ \omega = \sum_{k=1}^{n+1}x_k dy_k - y_k dx_k$$

It defines a form on the sphere. Since recently I learned that in order to make it a form on the sphere I need to calculate $i^\ast \omega$ where $i: S^{2n +1} \hookrightarrow \mathbb R^{2n + 2}$ I tried to that. For the map $i$ I used

$(x_1, \dots, x_{n+1}, y_1, \dots, y_n, \sqrt{1-x_1^2 - \dots - y_n^2})\mapsto (x_1, \dots, x_{n+1}, y_1, \dots, y_n, \sqrt{1-x_1^2 - \dots - y_n^2})$

And found that the restriction is

$$ i^\ast \omega = \sum_{k=1}^n x_k dy_k - y_k dx_k + x_{n+1} \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} {-x_k\over \sqrt{1-x_1^2-\dots -y_n^2}} dx_k + x_{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^n {-y_k\over \sqrt{1-x_1^2-\dots -y_n^2}} dy_k - \sqrt{1-x_1^2-\dots -y_n^2} dx_{n+1}$$

Since I expected this to be something nice I believe what I did is not optimal or perhaps even wrong.

Now I am wondering:

> To make a form on a manifold $M$ into a form on a submanifold $N$ is
>   it also possible to use charts for the pullback? Could I specify the
>   form just in such a local expression? And if so, is it equivalent to
>   expressing the pullback as a global expression?

**Edit**

Here's an example to make my question clearer:

An example on $S^1$ is $\omega = xdy - y dx$ (which is a form on $\mathbb R^2$). But $i^\ast \omega = d\theta$. That's the restriction calculated using the inclusion map. Alternatively, one can take a chart on $S^1$. E.g. projection onto $x$-axis. Then wlog $y=1$ (any non-zero constant will do) and so the resulting form is something like $\omega = -dx$. This seems to be equivalent to restriction by inclusion.

Comment: There are notational issues with your inclusion map. You mean to write the map $\iota$ using a chart, so it should be $\iota(x_1,\dots,x_{n+1},y_1,\dots,y_n) = (x_1,\dots,x_{n+1},y_1,\dots,y_n,\sqrt{1-x_1^2-\dots-y_n^2})$.

Comment: @TedShifrin I don't understand. The inclusion map in $S^1$ in polar coordinates is $(\cos \theta, \sin \theta) \mapsto (\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$ that is, the identity map. So it seems logical to me that in Cartesian coordinates in $n$ dimensions it will also be the identity map, too. Why is it not?

Comment: Your mapping should send the independent variable (giving your local coordinates) to the position in space.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to use $(x_1,\dots,x_{n+1},y_1,\dots,y_n)$ as local coordinates on the sphere (where $y_{n+1}\ne 0$), here's a somewhat easier way to do your pullback calculation. Note that because $x_1^2+\dots+x_{n+1}^2+y_1^2+\dots+y_{n+1}^2=1$, we have
$$\sum_{i=k}^{n+1} x_k\,dx_k + y_k\,dy_k = 0,$$
and so
$$dy_{n+1} = -\frac1{y_{n+1}}\big(\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} x_k\,dx_k + \sum_{k=1}^n y_k\,dy_k\big).$$
Thus, the pullback of $\omega$ is
$$\iota^*\omega = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \big(x_k-\frac{x_{n+1}y_k}{y_{n+1}}\big)dy_k
-\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\big(y_k-\frac{x_{n+1}x_k}{y_{n+1}}\big)dx_k.$$

Comment: This is indeed somewhat simpler. But what about my question about using charts and local expression vs. inclusion map and global expression?

Comment: It's pretty much impossible to give a global expression other than the original one. Rarely do manifolds have a single chart.

Comment: An example on $S^1$ is $\omega = xdy - y dx$ (which is a form on $\mathbb R^2$). But $i^\ast \omega = d\theta$. That's the restriction calculated using the inclusion map. Alternatively, one can take a chart on $S^1$. E.g. projection onto $x$-axis. Then wlog $y=1$ (any non-zero constant will do) and so the resulting form is something like $\omega = -dx$. This seems to be equivalent to restriction by inclusion. But maybe only in this example.

Comment: Be careful writing $d\theta$ ... $\theta$ is not globally defined on the circle (or else the integral would be $0$, not $2\pi$. I have no idea idea what your "wlog $y=1$" sentence means. Only at a single point is $\omega=-dx$.